# Find top value and its brand name from excel using python?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

As i'm trying to get the highest values from excel with its all row values..Can Any one Help me.

```
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        import pandas as pd
        from pandas import  DataFrame
        excel_file = 'FIRST1.xls'
        mov = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
        df = DataFrame(mov, columns=["PURCHASEQUANTITY", "PURCHASE AMOUNT", "SUBPRODUCTS"])
```

> This is my sample data from this data i want to sort in ascending order with its SUBPRODUCTS name
>
> ```
> PURCHASEQUANTITY PURCHASE AMOUNT SUBPRODUCTS 
> 2                            100 Chairs 
> 9                            200 sofa 
> 5                            300 bed 
> 6                            150 mirror 
> 7                             30 fridge 
> 5                            202 tables 
> 8                            100 showcase 
> 5                             50 tv
> ```

Comment: Can you please share, a bit of your data so that it could be reproducible to help you? Also you need the highest value as a single value or want them to be sorted like in your code?

Comment: PURCHASEQUANTITY  PURCHASE AMOUNT SUBPRODUCTS
             2              100      Chairs
             9              200        sofa
             5              300         bed
             6              150      mirror
             7               30      fridge
             5              202      tables
             8              100    showcase
             5               50          tv

Comment: This is my sample data from this data i want to short in ascending order with its SUBPRODUCTS name

Comment: @PriyaSRI please modify your qustion and dont post data example in the comments. Plus, what is the expected output? what is the error that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort in ascending order by the column "PURCHASE AMOUNT" and know the `subproduct` you can use:

```
df.sort_values("PURCHASE AMOUNT", inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   PURCHASEQUANTITY  PURCHASE AMOUNT SUBPRODUCTS
4                 7               30      fridge
7                 5               50          tv
0                 2              100      Chairs
6                 8              100    showcase
3                 6              150      mirror
1                 9              200        sofa
5                 5              202      tables
2                 5              300         bed
```

And:

```
print df.iloc[-1]

PURCHASEQUANTITY      5
PURCHASE AMOUNT     300
SUBPRODUCTS         bed
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Comment: @PriyaSRI happy it helped :)

Comment: sorry to say this it returns some error after running     df.sort_values("PURCHASE AMOUNT", inplace=False)
TypeError: sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'

Comment: and in this way: `df.sort_values(by="PURCHASE AMOUNT", inplace=True) ` ?

Comment: i got the output..Thank You @joe

Comment: i have another doubt here actually i tried to get data based on two column name U_ID and P_ID i replace the code "getda = df1[df1['U_ID'] == int(8) and df1['P_ID'] == int(3)].values " but it returns the error like Valuerror The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()..Can you please explan this

Comment: @PriyaSRI Maybe is better to open a new question. From the format of the comments it is not really clear.

Comment: Sorry For this @joe i got the output now